# view does not render when using a form_with, with a url and existing controller action in ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, model-view-controller, routes

When I attempt to submit a post request using `form_with` and a custom url pointing to an existing controller action, the view does not render.

I am trying to follow a tutorial which shows the differences between `form_for` and `form_tag` in ROR, but trying to use `form_with` instead because the former are going to be deprecated. It all works fine using the `form_tag`.

The [Rails Guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html) for form helpers only shows `form_for` and `form_tag`.

The [ROR API docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_with) does show some examples with `form_with`, but I am not connecting the dots.

```
<!-- index.html.erb -->

<%= form_with(url: create_users_path) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :name, placeholder: "Your Name" %>
  <%= f.number_field :age, placeholder: "Your Age" %>
  <%= f.submit "Create Profile" %>
<% end %>
```

and

```
  # routes.rb

  get 'users' => 'welcome#users'
  post 'create_users' => 'welcome#users'
```

and

```
# welcome_controller.rb

def users
  if params[:name] != nil
    user = User.create(name: params[:name], age: params[:age])
  end
  @users = User.all
end
```

and

```
<!--users.html.erb-->
<table border="2">
<tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Age</th>
</tr>

<% @users.each do |user| %>
    <tr>
        <td><%= user.name %></td>
        <td><%= user.age %></td>
    </tr>
<% end %>

</table>
<br>
<%= link_to "Return to Index", root_path %>
```

My users table updates with the data sent in the form, but I am left on my `index.html.erb` view instead of at `users.html.erb` where I expect, as the `.create` active record call is in the `users` action.

And here are my server logs from the `POST` request where `welcome/users.html.erb` is said to have been rendered (browser doesn't update.)  A `GET` will render the page in the browser.

```
Started POST "/create_users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-08-05 22:18:26 -0400
Processing by WelcomeController#users as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"upoeRgVioYXs+Z+vsyBdg4CnXrSTOMCzPFXSHUKT2IlrVMDtvnf8UD7yJkPMYw0zkwihmPvY3Yq0BlG7RFsIIQ==", "name"=>"testy testerson", "age"=>"28", "commit"=>"Create Profile"}
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (2.4ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("name", "age", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["name", "testy testerson"], ["age", 28], ["created_at", "2018-08-06 02:18:26.466212"], ["updated_at", "2018-08-06 02:18:26.466212"]]
   (3.2ms)  commit transaction
  Rendering welcome/users.html.erb within layouts/application
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users"
  Rendered welcome/users.html.erb within layouts/application (4.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 147ms (Views: 56.8ms | ActiveRecord: 6.7ms)


Started GET "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-08-05 22:19:19 -0400
Processing by WelcomeController#users as HTML
  Rendering welcome/users.html.erb within layouts/application
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users"
  Rendered welcome/users.html.erb within layouts/application (2.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 60ms (Views: 51.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)
```

I am pretty sure that having the create and show in the same action is not a best practice...just trying to get a better understanding of rails. What am I missing about the routes/controller/views relationship?

I am using rails versrion 5.1.6

Comment: You should dive into `form_with` and read about it. I am pretty sure `form_with` is defaulted to `remote: true` (Ajax) which means your view should be an `js.erb` view not an `html.erb` view. If you want an `html` view instead, there is an option to add to your form helper. (I recon this is strange as `form_for` does not default to JS). (Also form_with is rather new, I am still stuck with form_for and form_tag, they are probably easier to play with)

Comment: Can you show the server logs?

Comment: @JagdeepSingh Server logs for POST and GET added.

Comment: @Maxence Yes, `form_for` and `form_tag` are a little easier for me to understand.  I would like to be able to understand form_with (and Rails!) better, which created this current issue.  If I understand you correctly, I should be able to add `local: true` and my `users.html.erb` file should render, but this behaves the same way as the default.

Comment: Your request format is JS. You need to respond to that by adding a new template _welcome/users.js.erb_

Comment: You definitely need `local: true`. Also you can remove the brackets. `form_with` has a very simple syntax. Separate arguments with just commas.

Comment: The only problem that makes it not work is a wrong syntax on the form tag, I don't see anything else at the moment. `form_with url: create_users_path, local: true do ..` should work. Also be careful, By merging Create and Index your application is no longer RESTful. People can probably create users with a get request instead of a post request. This can produce a security breach.

Comment: @Maxence I agree that combining the two in the same action isn't good.  The tutorial I was following for `form_tag` showed it _could_ be done and I was just attempting to reproduce that using `form_with`.